# What the diff between webpack in npm script and javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

During writing my `webpack.config.js`

After is my webpack config result object:

```
Object {
  entry: Object, 
  module: Object,
  resolve: Object,
  plugins: Array(2),
  output: Object
}
```

Here are two ways to run webpack:

#### a. in npm script

webpack --config webpack.config.js

#### b. in build.js

webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stat) => {})

---

What the diff between these two ways?

They will create different result. Why?

Comment: Is `They will create different result.` an obersavtion, that they really created differnt results for you, or is that a question if the may produce different results?

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference at all.

The first option is a cli based, which uses the second way internally (node api).

They produce the same output, if the same options are passed.